# How to find he eigenvalues and eigenvectors of $L$?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $L:\Bbb R^3\rightarrow \Bbb R^3$ be defined by $L[a_1,a_2,a_3]=[-a_2,  a_1+a_2, a_1-a_3]$. Using natural basis for $\Bbb R^3$, find the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of $L$.

How do I represent with a characteristic equation?

Comment: As you wrote in your question: use the natural basis of $R^3$ to write down the square matrix associated to $L$. Then compute its characteristic polynomial ($\det( \dots)$) and solve.

Answer (score 1):

We are asked to find all eigenpairs of the linear map
\begin{array}{ccc}
\Bbb R^3 & \xrightarrow{L} & \Bbb R^3 \\
\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\\z \end{bmatrix} & \mapsto & \begin{bmatrix} -y\\x+y\\x-z\end{bmatrix}
\end{array}
The standard basis for $\Bbb R^3$ is $\beta=\{e_1,e_2,e_3\}$ where
\begin{align*}                                                                                 
e_1 &= \begin{bmatrix}1\\0\\0\end{bmatrix} &                                                   
e_2 &= \begin{bmatrix}0\\1\\0\end{bmatrix} &                                                   
e_3 &= \begin{bmatrix}0\\0\\1\end{bmatrix}                                                     
\end{align*}
To compute the matrix of $L$ relative to $\beta$, note that
\begin{array}{rcrcrcrc}
L(e_1) & = & \color{red}{0}\,e_1 & + & \color{green}{1}\,e_2 & + & \color{blue}{1}\,e_3 \\
L(e_2) & = & \color{red}{-1}\,e_1 & + & \color{green}{1}\,e_2 & + & \color{blue}{0}\,e_3 \\
L(e_3) & = & \color{red}{0}\,e_1 & + & \color{green}{0}\,e_2 & + & \color{blue}{-1}\,e_3
\end{array}
This implies
$$
[L]_\beta^\beta=
\begin{bmatrix}
\color{red}{0} & \color{red}{-1} & \color{red}{0} \\
\color{green}{1} & \color{green}{1} & \color{green}{0} \\
\color{blue}{1} & \color{blue}{0} & \color{blue}{-1}
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Our problem is now equivalent to finding the eigenvalues and corresponding eigenvectors of $[L]_\beta^\beta$. Do you know how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

The matrix for $L$ is

$$\left[\begin{array}{ccc}
0 & 1 & 1\\
-1 & 1 &0\\
0 & 0 & -1\\
\end{array}\right]
$$
So you need the determinant of
$$\left[\begin{array}{ccc}
-\lambda & 1 & 1\\
-1 & 1-\lambda &0\\
0 & 0 & -1-\lambda\\
\end{array}\right]
$$
Set it equal to zero and solve for the three roots.  $\lambda=-1$ clearly makes the matrix singular, so that is a root, which should make finding the other two easy.

Comment: where did you get the matrix for L?

Comment: Sorry I had it wrong (typo), I think it's right now